# ActiveMQ Messages appear to be dequeued from one broker but not arrive at other in Network of Brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a network of brokers, whereby messages are produced from a Java app onto a small local broker in the field, this then has a static network destination for the queue pointing at a broker (in AWS), which has a consumer sat across all the queues for the remote brokers.

If there is any interruption in the connection, the remote broker will reconnect successfully. The issue is that in some cases, the remote broker will reconnect, the queue on the remote broker will appear to rack up the dequeue count, however the central broker to which it is meant to be forwarding doesn't show up an increasing enqueue for the queue.

The messages enqueued at the remote end are Persistent = YES, priority = 4. If I manually add a message on the broker with Persistent = Yes, the same behaviour exhibits. If I set persistent = NO, the message successfully hits the other end. If I restart the broker, the persistent messages flow again (although the ones it thought it was successfully sending are lost).

What situation could cause this loss of messages, and is there a configuration option that can be tweaked to fix this?

The configuration for the remote brokers is a standard AMQ install, with the following network connector defined:

```xml
        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector
                    uri="${X.remoteMsgURI}"
                    staticBridge="true"
                    dynamicOnly="false"
                    alwaysSyncSend="true"
                    userName="${X.remoteUsername}"
                    password="${X.remotePassword}"
            >
                <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
                    <queue physicalName="cloud.${X.environment}.queue.${X.queuebase}"/>
                </staticallyIncludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
        </networkConnectors>
```

The connection string for the static remote is:

```
remoteMsgURI=static:(failover:(ssl:/X-1.mq.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:61617?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000,ssl://X-2.amazonaws.com:61617?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000))
```

Comment: There is not enough information provided to troubleshoot the issue. Try adding the logging broker plugin to track message flow during the time period when there is an interrupted connection. Then share that back.

Comment: Will try that, the issue with that might be that they're on rather low powered SBCs, with a fairly high rate of messages, and often it takes a fair while for the issue to manifest.